# Tomcat default session handling

Tags: session, tomcat

I am currently facing an issue and would like to know if i am going in the right direction.

I have a single servlet that is hit by the users. Currently i do not have any session handling code.. When two users, each from a different machine hit the same servlet at approximately same time on the same tomcat instance, it mixes up the session data causing user1's data to be shown on user2's screen.

I believe this is because i am not handling sessions and relying on default sessions created by tomcat. Hence, i would have to explicitly use session handling in the servlet to ensure that the right data is being processed ? Perhaps as described [here](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/servlets/session_api.shtml) ?

Thanks,
Qadeer

Comment: Could you please post your code? If your users are seeing each others data, the problems is probably in your code, not Tomcats session handling.

Comment: @NilsH thanks for your input.. You were right.. it was indeed issue with my code. I had a closer look into my code and found that i was not returning the right bean object in a multi-request scenario.

Thanks again.. Your input was really helpful..!

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved after reading through the input from @NilsH. It was a problem with my code that it was overwriting bean objects in the session, without notice and hence, the same data was being displayed to both users who accessed the same url at approximately same time.

I did not have to do anything for session handling to resolve this! Thanks again !